# Meteor - How can I get server data from a URL parameter?

Tags: meteor, client-server, single-page-application, iron-router

I'm trying to return different data based off a URL parameter on a route in MeteorJS.

From a nodejs background, I would just do this:

```
testPage = function (req, res, next) {
    //Got parameter query from url
    console.log('Getting at /testPage/:query '+req.params.query);

    //do something with that parameter, say make an HTTP call or query database
    var newThing = req.params.query+"hi";

    // render the page
    var data = {
        foo: newThing
    };
    res.render('testPage', data);
};
```

Meteor doesn't support server side rendering, so that's out. I'm still wrapping my head around the single-page client rendering of Meteor; how should I go about this in Meteor?

My first attempt (using IronRouter):

```
Router.route('/testPage/:query', function () {
    console.log("Got param at /testPage/:query "+this.params.query);
    if(Meteor.isServer){
        console.log("This code may never be called?");
        //Otherwise, make an HTTP call 
        //  and then somehow pass the data back to the client...
    }
    this.render("query");
});
```

Is this something I can do with reactive variables? Or perhaps make an AJAX call from client to separate server endpoint?

Comment: I would suggest getting the query parameters on the client when the route changes.  Then call a server method with the new parameters.  Router.current() is reactive, so you can check for its parameters inside an autorun, and put your method call inside as well.  If I have time I'll try to make a Meteorpad to demonstrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical pattern for this with iron-router is to subscribe to data using the route parameter(s):

```
Router.route('/foo/:bar',{ // Route takes a single parameter
  name: 'foo',
  waitOn: function(){
    return Meteor.subscribe('fooPublication', this.params.bar);
  }
});
```

In this example `this.params.bar` is the route's only parameter. It is passed as an argument to `Meteor.subscribe`. The server can use that parameter in deciding what to publish back to the client. The `waitOn` guarantees the data will be available on the client when the template renders.

Comment: For anyone else who doesn't really understand subscribe/publish, I put Meteor.publish in my base server code, and it gets called when this subscribe function is called! Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data on the .render method as a second argument

```
Router.route('/testPage/:query', function () {
    console.log("Got param at /testPage/:query "+this.params.query);
    if(Meteor.isServer){
        console.log("This code may never be called?");
        //Otherwise, make an HTTP call 
        //  and then somehow pass the data back to the client...
    }
    this.render("query", {data: queryResult });
});
```